# What is the proper way to store and read data in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that uses(used) localStorage a lot for checking whether a user was logged in (ie: `if (localStorage.getItem("username")) {..User logged in. Do stuff}`.
I am updating the extension to use Manifest v3 and am trying to switch to chrome.storage.local and it is causing some grief as it's no longer a simple fact to check the localStorage item and then do stuff due to the asynchronicity (Is that a word?) of chrome.storage.
With that, I know I am going to make some pretty significant changes so I wanted to get some feedback on how other people would handle this.
As mentioned, once a user is logged in successfully, their username is saved in localStorage and we check that before running most functions. I am thinking that we could use a `"loggedIn"` status variable in chrome.storage at login and then have something in the onChange on logout for chrome.storage to reset that but what would be the best way to keep track of a `"loggedIn"` status variable. This would need to be accessed by the service_worker and the content pages. This also should be persistent and the data should be available even if the browser is closed and re-opened.
I have a couple of ideas but would like to hear how other would approach this.

Comment: This is a pretty standard task of switching to asynchronous paradigm, the simplest form is to use async+await syntax, so if you need further assistance please show your current code ([MCVE](/help/mcve)).

Comment: I have a similar issue, may I know what you did in the end?

Comment: @aderchox. I ended up creating a preference object in the service worker on extension install and saving it to chrome.storage and calling it when needed. I did have an issue with authentication though. Since I couldn't find a really secure way to save credentials since any decryption code would be easily accessible, I decided to store credentials (password) to memory only. It is an inconvenience having to login frequently but it has to do for now.